# How to create block to list all children of an entity?

Tags: views, entities, 9

I want to list all the nodes that have the currently viewed node as their parent.

To make this more tangible and less abstract, let's do an example:

---

I have a content type `Locations` which has an *Entity Reference* field called `parent_location` with an unlimited number of values.

For example:

```
- USA (3)                             [country level]
  - New York (4)                        [state level]
    - New York City (6)                   [city level]
      - Central Park (8)                    [landmark level]
      - Empire State Building (9)           [landmark level]
      - Times Square (10)                   [landmark level]
  - Illinois (5)                        [state level]
    - Chicago (7)                         [city level]
      - Sears Tower (11)                    [landmark level]
      - That bean looking thing (12)        [landmark level]
```

So when I view the content for **USA (3)**, I wanna list all the children, meaning **New York (4)** and **Illinois (5)**.

When I view **New York City (6)** I want to list **Central Park (8)**, **Empire State Building (9)**, and **Times Square (10)**.

I want these to show up when I view `/node/6` and be clickable, so that I can browse this nested child/parent structure.

It's already possible by default to traverse UP on the tree. Meaning I can easily get from **Times Square (10)** all the way up to **USA (3)**.

---

However, I can't figure out how to list all children of the appropriate level!

I did create a block view called `List Child Locations`. And I've placed this view on the block `Content`. It shows up correctly, but it does not list the appropriate children.

[image: Listing too many children]

---

When it comes to editing my view, I have no clue what I'm doing or how...

I see there's two options:

`admin/structure/views/view/list_child_locations/edit/block_1`

and

`admin/structure/views/view/list_child_locations/edit/entity_reference_1`

I think I have to do something with contextual filters, while I'm in the Entity Reference Display. But I can't find anything that looks like what I need...

[image: View Settings]

Out of all those many options, which one do I chose to make sure it does something like

`SELECT * from Locations WHERE parent_location = %current_location%` ?

What's the right settings for my entity display to only list the children?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figured it out!

First, I learned more about contextual filters and relationships, and what they each mean and do (relationships basically relates to the FROM query, contextual filters to the WHERE query)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mRWtpcUm9pI

Another user had a similar question and solved it like so:

https://www.drupal.org/project/views/issues/1724396

So all I had to do was:

`/admin/structure/views/add`

- show content of type "Locations"
- Create a block

Then under "advanced" add a contextual filter, check "parent_location (field_parent_location)", press the button to "Add and configure".

Then under "When no filter is available" say "provide a default value" and select "content ID from URL"

Hit apply, save the view.

Under `/admin/structure/block` place the block to the content region and make it visible for Locations.

This was super simple! :-)

Comment: The only problem I have with this method: Will it still work when I make my URLs pretty and SEO friendly?

Comment: This still works even with SEO friendly URLs